# extending a service to create a single definition of a database throughout application

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've created a nodejs service to create/interact with databases.

```
class CRUDService {
  private section: string;
  private db: any;

  constructor(section: string) {
    this.section = section;
    this.db = new DB('.' + section);
  }

  public create(data: any): Promise<string> {
    ...
  }

  public retrieve(id: string): Promise<string> {
    ...
  }

  public update(id: any, data: any): Promise<string> {
    ...
  }

  public delete(item: any): Promise<string> {
    ...
  }

  public all(): Promise<string> {
    ...
  }
}

export {CRUDService};
```

And then I was using it by passing a database name to it:

```
this.db1 = new DatabaseService('database-one');
this.db2 = new DatabaseService('database-two');
```

This has been working well for me but recently I noticed that I am defining the same databases over and over again (in different modules) and figured there has got to be a better way to doing it so that the database can be defined once and shared across everything.

Is there a way I can extend my current service to define/initialize the database once and reference it?

```
export class DbOneService extends CRUDservice {
  protected section = 'database-one';
}
```

And then use it like:

```
this.db1 = DbOneService;
```

I'm just a bit lost and the above doesn't seem to work.

---

UPDATE

---

By leaving the CRUDService as-is I was able to achieve what I by

```
import {CRUDService} from '../crud.service';

function DbOneService() {
  return new CRUDService('database-one');
}

export {DbOneService};
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
import {DbOneService} from 'db/database-one';

const DbOneServiceDB = DbOneService();

DbOneServiceDB.all(){...}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: You could simply export the instance instead of the class, `export default new DatabaseService('database-one');`

Comment: I'd suggest you to read about Singleton Design Pattern.
Export your singleton with a function like "getDB(name)". This function will check if the "name" is already exists into some object container (Array or Object).